# How to reduce the size of \limits

Tags: equations, fontsize

How can I reduce the size of the lower limit? I'd like to make it smaller.

```
$\lim\limits_{\Delta P \to 0}$
```

Adding `\tiny` doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\scriptscriptstyle` for a smaller script size when in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\lim\limits_{\scriptscriptstyle\Delta P \to 0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one doesn't like the aspect-ratio constraint of the `\scriptscriptstyle`, one can start with the default `\scriptstyle` and scale the result, here by .7.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\lim\limits_{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptstyle\Delta P \to 0$}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmm... that makes it vertically smaller, but doesn't change the horizontal scale that much (I wanted it not to stick out so much past the `lim`)

Comment: @JasonS That is because, at least for the default computer-modern font, smaller fontsize is squeezed more vertically than horizontally (a choice of the font designer).

Comment: @JasonS You could combine aspects of the two answers with something like: `$\lim\limits_{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle\Delta P \to 0$}}$`

Comment: if I use `scriptstyle` rather than `scriptscriptstyle` it looks very good... if you edit your answer to include that as an alternative, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I muddled my way through using `scalebox`, although I don't know how to get it to change the relative size rather than absolute:

```
$\lim\limits_{\scalebox{0.4}{$\Delta P \to 0$}}$
```

[image]

or this, which looks slightly better:

```
$\lim\limits_{\scalebox{0.6}{$^{\Delta P \to 0}$}}$
```

[image]

or even better:

```
$\lim\limits_{\scalebox{0.7}{$\scriptstyle\Delta P \to 0$}}$
```

[image]